# Apache Rewrite to new folder not working (works for existing folders)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have a .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*da.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/HTML2/    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thedavidsonagency/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the same directory I have a folder thedavidsonagency/ with index.php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
```

index.php is the only file in thedavidsonagency/ directory.

If I visit `localhost/thedavidsonagency/` I see the message

```
Hello World
```

however, visiting da.com give me a 500 internal server error

I have tried changing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thedavidsonagency/$1 [L,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ashley/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The directory ashley is already setup previously. Visiting da.com now sends me to the ashley website no problems!

I am running PHP 5.3.8, apache 2.2.21 (setup with XAMPP)

On windows 7 in a local environment, and setup the Hosts file:

```
localhost da.com
```

I actually have several other entries just like this for different folders (websites). And all of them work just fine. But adding this new entry in my htaccess to this new folder does not work.

Any suggestions?? Is there a cache I can clear somewhere? I have tried restarting apache and my computer with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} da\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(HTML2|thedavidsonagency)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thedavidsonagency/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Well this also works. I like how explicit your rules are so I am going to use them. However, it just started working after a while. I didn't change anything in the htaccess or configuration files. Not sure what happened, maybe the cache cleared? Wasn't aware of a caching ssytem for the htaccess files though...

Comment: htaccess is not cached but there might be caching elsewhere like code/framework/browser etc.